# why does default value for char data type in java has 4 hex when it is a 16 bit datatype

Tags: java

I am new to java, and this question may be silly to many.

When going through the basics, i learnt this:

char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

My question is why does the default, minimum and maximum have 4 hex when it can be only one?

Comment: Why do you think it can only be one?

Comment: @max I think OP means it can only have 1 value (at a time) but it seems to have 1 “u” and 4 “f” values.

Comment: *Exactly* what do you mean by “one value” and “4 hex”? Do you now about hex literals?

Comment: Thanks @bohemian , I completely missed the point ,  that one F is binary 1111 ( and exactly fits 4 bits). Super silly me :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Hex F is decimal 15 or binary 1111. It fits exactly in 4 bits. a 16-bit value can hold 4 times 4 bits, hence from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF (which is 2^16 = 65,536).

The \u in your example is for Unicode, pretty much saying that you can store unicode characters that take up to 16 bits, from \u0000 to \uFFFF.

Comment: Thanks @robert , now I get it perfectly, I had completely overlooked the fact that one F is binary 1111 (and fits exactly 4 bits) . The question was super silly to have been asked in a forum :) :). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to read up on numeral systems.

Binary: Represents numbers using 2 digits, 0 and 1.

Decimal: Represents numbers using 10 digits, 0 - 9.

Hexadecimal: Represents numbers using 16 digits, 0 - F.

A char in Java is a type that can hold numbers with 16 bits, i.e. in the range 0 - 1111111111111111 in binary, 0 - 65535 in decimal or 0 - FFFF in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks @max , I completely missed the point ,  that that one F is binary 1111 ( and exactly fits 4 bits)